# Navigate to previously focused window in xmonad

Tags: window, xmonad, focus

Is there any module that supports this functionality? If not - does anyone know how to implement this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found a solution posted here: https://www.reddit.com/r/xmonad/comments/1oi2xs/how_to_jump_back_from_master_window/

```
import XMonad.Actions.GroupNavigation
main = xmonad $ defaultConfig { logHook = historyHook }
```

Keybinding:

```
, ((modm, xK_b), nextMatch History (return True))
```

A small limitation is, it focuses the previous window (that may not be in the current workspace).

Answer (score 1):

An excellent module, `XMonad.Hooks.RefocusLast`, has since been added to xmonad-contrib, which does a great job of tracking the most recently focused window on a per workspace basis.

https://hackage.haskell.org/package/xmonad-contrib-0.16/docs/XMonad-Hooks-RefocusLast.html